# Type an object with optional keys, but non-null value for keys that exist

Tags: typescript

I'm on TypeScript 3.2.2 with `strict: true`.

I've been unable to type a plain object that has a set of dynamically defined keys, but all those keys have a guaranteed non-null value type.

[[TypeScript playground example]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20function%20values%3CT%3E(something%3A%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%20%7D)%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20AnyObject%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ObjectMap%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20object1%3A%20ObjectMap%3CAnyObject%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20key1%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20key2%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%3B%20%0D%0Aconst%20valuesOfObject1%20%3D%20values(object1)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20AnyObject%5B%5D%20%E2%9C%85%0D%0Aconst%20propertyAccess1%20%3D%20object1%5B'lalala'%5D.foo%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20Should've%20errored%20%E2%9D%8C%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Trying%20to%20fix%20property%20access%0D%0Ainterface%20NullableObjectMap%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20T%20%7C%20undefined%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20object2%3A%20NullableObjectMap%3CAnyObject%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20key1%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20key2%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D%3B%20%0D%0Aconst%20valuesOfObject2%20%3D%20values(object2)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20(AnyObject%20%7C%20undefined)%5B%5D%20%E2%9D%8C%20%0D%0Aconst%20propertyAccess2%20%3D%20object2%5B'lalala'%5D.foo%3B%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%E2%9C%85%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Ideal%20syntax%0D%0Ainterface%20ObjectMapWithNonNullTypeForDefinedKeys%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3F%3A%20T%20%2F%2F%20doesn't%20compile%20%E2%9D%8C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

```js
// Will assume any property access has type T
interface Object<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}

// Will assume Object.values() could be undefined
interface Object<T> {
    [key: string]: T | undefined;
}


// Doesn't compile
interface Object<T> {
    [key: string]?: T;
}
```

Comment: And what's a question?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't really do a great job [distinguishing missing properties from `undefined` properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195).  How do you expect to use this?  Once you have a string index signature, it will allow you to get and set any key, which means the only safe property type is `T | undefined`.

Comment: Also relevant issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778

Comment: @jcalz I'm using `T | undefined` now and dealing with it when working with values in mapping functions or lodash. But seems like it's a language limitation. The issue you linked describes exactly the problem I'm facing. I'll accept it if you post your comments as an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, TypeScript doesn't do a great job of [distinguishing missing properties from `undefined` properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195).  That's at least somewhat reasonable, since when you read a missing property from an object in JavaScript you will get `undefined` (and not an error).  And before the [`--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks) was introduced in TypeScript 2.0, TypeScript did a very bad job of distinguishing missing/undefined properties from present/defined properties.  This was mostly addressed by `--strictNullChecks` but a few issues linger.

One of the places that this issue still shows up is in [types with index signatures](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778).  Index signatures are just considered to be present.  There is no way to say some keys are present and some keys are absent with an index signature.  The [optional index signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7118) syntax you want is not part of the language. With `--strictNullChecks` turned on, the signature `{[k: string]: SomeType}` is saying that every single string-key property exists and is of type `SomeType`, but this is not actually enforced when you assign objects to it.  The only truly type safe way to use index signatures is to add `| undefined` to the value type, like `{[k: string]: SomeType | undefined}`, but this ends up becoming very annoying to use in many circumstances, leading to people overusing non-null assertions, which  [doesn't help anyone](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11238#issuecomment-250562397).  So it is the way it is.

---

#### UPDATE for TS4.1

TS4.1 will introduce a [`--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1-beta/#no-unchecked-indexed-access), also known as "pedantic index signatures" which behaves mostly like `| undefined` has been added to the index signature.  This is still annoying to use in the way mentioned above, especially for string index signatures (arrays are less bad since you can make a `for..of` loop that doesn't worry about `undefined`), so the rest of this answer mostly stands.

---

Right now your options are, as I see them:

- use an index signature without `| undefined` and deal with the fact that the compiler thinks all properties are present when some are not (do checks that the compiler doesn't think are necessary, like `if (unknownKey in foo) {... foo[unknownKey] ...}`)
- use an index signature with `| undefined` (or use `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` in TS4.1+) and deal with the fact that the compiler keeps warning you that a value might not be defined when you know it is (do extra checks you don't need, like `const prop = foo[knownKey]; if (typeof prop !== 'undefined') { ... prop ... }`; or non-null assertions like `const prop = foo[knownKey]!`)
- don't use an index signature.  You might be able to get away with using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) where the set of keys is some union of literals that you don't know when you're defining your types but you will know when you are using it.  That is, use the predefined [`Record<K, T>`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1439-L1444) type:

  ```
    type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {[P in K]: T};
  ```

  But that gets more complicated when trying to manipulate, so I'm not going to dive too deeply in here.

Not sure what else to say.  It's a language limitation that persists because the alternatives seem to be more annoying.  If you have a compelling use case you might be able to comment on some of the linked GitHub issues or open a new one, but I don't expect much will change here.

Oh well, hope that's of some help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unknown type:

```js
interface Object {
    [key: string]: unknown;
}
```

From the TypeScript docs:

> [...] unknown is the type-safe counterpart of any. Anything is assignable to unknown, but unknown isn’t assignable to anything but itself and any without a type assertion or a control flow based narrowing. Likewise, no operations are permitted on an unknown without first asserting or narrowing to a more specific type.

Comment: The problem with `unknown` is that I'll completely lose the type of those values. If I do `Object.values().map(value => ...)` for example, I'd lose inference for the type of `value`.

Similarly, I want to be able to do `object['someKey'].property` and get an error that says value of `someKey` might be `undefined`.

Comment: It doesn't lose completely, you just have to use type assertions.