# Union with empty object results in type erasure

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Something%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Something%20%7C%20undefined%20%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20getSomething%20%3D%20(t%3A%20Test)%20%3D%3E%20t%5B'key'%5D%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%20%2F%2F%20Expecting%3A%20Something%20%7C%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%0A%2F%2F%20Usage%3A%0Adeclare%20const%20test%3A%20Test%3B%0A%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20getSomething(test).a%3B%20%2F%2F%20Expecting%3A%20string%20%7C%20undefined)

```js
interface Something {
    a: string;
}

interface Test {
    [key: string]: Something | undefined 

}
// Expecting: Something | {}
// Inferred: {}
const getSomething = (t: Test) => t['key'] || {}

// Usage:

declare const test: Test;

// Expecting: string | undefined
// Inferred: Error: `a` does not exist on type
const a = getSomething(test).a;
```

What is the reason that a union of `{}` with an object erases the object's type?

If I write:

```js
type EmptyObject = { [key: string]: undefined }
```

and use `{} as EmptyObject` instead, then things work as expected.

Comment: Even if `getSomething` type was inferred as `(t: Test) => Something | {}` you still would not be allowed to `getSomething(test).a`, since `a` does not exist in `{}`. But you could have used indexed access like `['a']`

Comment: @p.s.w.g your answer looks reasonable, why did you delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, union of `{}` with any non-primitive (object) type is reduced to just `{}` for the purpose of type checking. It's because in TypeScript, `{}` as a type does not really mean "an object with no properties", it means "an object with no **known** properties", so that usual type compatibility rules can be applied and `{}` can serve as ultimate super type.

So, adding anything to the union with `{}` does not really add any information known about the type - nothing is still known about properties of resulting type.

But inferring `{}` as the type for empty object literal in this code

```
const getSomething = (t: Test) => t['key'] || {}
```

indeed causes information loss, because **value** `{}` is known to have no properties, and because of that, if the resulting type has any properties they must have come from `Something` and `a` must have type `string` if it's present at all.

Maybe in the future TypeScript will be able to handle this with [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), but for now, there's one possible workaround which you found.

If you use type assertion `as {[n: string]: undefined}` for empty object,
you get the expected result because now the resulting type is calculated by going over common properties of the union type members and taking union of their types. So `Test` has `Something` as property type, and `undefined` comes from type assertion, giving `Something | undefined` as resulting property type.

[Conventionally](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936#issuecomment-462134690), `never` type is used instead of `undefined`, so you can define

```
type StricterEmptyObject = { [n in string]?: never };
```

which, again, works as expected because `never` is the opposite of `{}` and union of `never | undefined | Something` is `undefined | Something`.

```
// Inferred return type: Something | StricterEmptyObject
const getSomething = (t: Test) => t['key'] || {} as StricterEmptyObject;


declare const test: Test;

// inferred: string | undefined
const a = getSomething(test).a;
```

Comment: “Union of `{}` with any type gives you `{}`”... well, with any *object* type like `{foo: string}`, sure.  With primitive types like `string`, not so much.  I’m sure you know this already... but maybe some readers won’t?

Comment: Fixed, but it's more complicated because writing `type T = Something | {};` gives me `type T = {} | Something` in the tooltip for T. Surely it gets reduced at some time, and there are some relevant issues/PRs in the TypeScript repo but I can't find anything at the moment.

Comment: @artem Is the `Stricter` type actually stricter? For me it gets reduced to `{ [key: string]: undefined }`. jcalz actually explained why this happens in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54448348/870942) I'd posted.

Comment: @Shayan yes you are right, with `--strictNullChecks` it's the same as `{ [key: string]: undefined }`. It's different with `--strictNullChecks` off, no idea how useful it is.